# Is it possible to navigate back to the last cursor position in the *same* window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I usually use multiple tab groups (multiple windows separated into groups).

When I navigate back to the last cursor position using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, it navigates regardless of windows. So, when it navigates to a window that I wasn't working on, I lose track of what line of code I was previously looking at in that window.

Is it possible to navigate only in the current editing window?

(It seems like similar functionality exists in Visual Studio Code according to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51967840/10027592).)